# After mounting using sshfs I cannot commit my changes using subversion

Tags: svn, sshfs

local machine:
    Fedora 13 
    Subversion: 1.6.9

```
remote machine:
CentSO 5.3
subversion 1.4.2
```

I have a project which is on the remote machine:

```
remote@x.x.x.x:projects/ssd1
```

I have mounted this on my local machine:

```
sshfs remote@x.x.x.x:projects/ssd1 /home/jbloggs/projects/mnt/ssd1
```

Everything mounts ok. So I open my project using GNU Emacs 23.2.1. When I want to comment my changes in emacs I get the following error:

```
can't move /home/jbloggs/projects/mnt/ssd1/.svn/tmp/entries to /home/jbloggs/mnt/ssd1/.svn/entries: Operation not permitted
```

Does anyone know of any way I can resolve this issue?

many thanks for any advice,

Comment: @Ether: Would you explain what differentiates tags 'svn' and 'subversion' ?

Comment: @Amardeep: `[svn]` is the canonical tag. `[subversion]` is a deprecated duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue is with sshfs, rather than Subversion. The short answer is: try the "rename workaround" option:

```
 sshfs -o workaround=rename ...
```

If that doesn't help see if you can rename the file manually using the Linux `mv` command (not the SVN one). If not, can you rename it using SFTP (ie. without using sshfs)? See http://www.mail-archive.com/macfuse-devel@googlegroups.com/msg00559.html for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: I thought about using the move command, but you can't move between working copies and repos, only WC -> WC and Repo -> Repo.  

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re18.html 

That's why I think he'll need to setup an identical path on the local machine, otherwise, he won't be able to perform svn actions in  *both* locations.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the shell `mv` command, leaving Subversion out of the picture entirely. Then, if that fail leave sshfs out of the picture, too, by using SFTP.

Comment: Sorry for the late delay in marking this. However, I have not had time to check as I have been very busy. But I will take you word for it that your solution works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think what may be going on here is that you checked out the working copy on the remote machine, and it checked out to one path, but on the mounted drive, you're working under a different path.

How different are the two paths on the local and remote machine? Would it be possible for you to make the paths identical?

I would unmount the drive, remount it with the exact same path as the path on the remote machine, do an svn cleanup, and try to commit then.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are mounting the project path from the remote machine? Wouldn't it be easier to *checkout* a working copy on the local machine?

Comment: +1 go with something like svn+ssh to get your local working copy and try again.

Comment: Not necessarily. I have a similar setup, where I edit the code files on one machine and compile them on another, and I don't want to have to check in every time before I compile.